# MySQL вывод 2 логинов из одной таблицы одним запросом

Tags: mysql, база-данных, join

Столкнулся с проблемой. У меня есть таблица в которой хранятся данные о блокировках
userid, adminid, reason для примера 123, 321, "Неадекват"
Также есть таблица в которой id пользователей и логины - userid, login

Не могу придумать как вернуть одним запросом из базы блокировок имя пользователя и администратора.

На данный момент сделал так, но думаю это не правильно.

```
SELECT users.login,ban.reason
FROM ban
INNER JOIN users
WHERE users.userid IN(ban.userid, ban.adminid) AND ban.userid = 123
```

Но в таком варианте я получаю 2 ответа что совсем не удобно

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.login, a.login, b.reason
FROM ban b
LEFT JOIN users u on b.userid = u.userid
LEFT JOIN users a on b.adminid = a.userid
WHERE b.userid = 123
```